# CORS with Axios: Cookie arrives client, but not saved for future requests

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios

I send a get request from the client side:

```
const withCredentials = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true
});
const data = {
    login: this.state.login,
    password: this.state.password,
}
withCredentials.post('http://localhost:9000/login', data)
```

And I can see in the developer tools that the cookie arrives at the client side, meaning CORS is configured correctly for the server side. But the cookie is not saved for future requests, and is not sent with them.

Weirdly, if I send the same request again to '/login', the cookie is actually sent with the request. I want it to be added to all requests.

How can I tell Axios to add the cookie to all requests? How come it is sent automatically with the same request but not with others, even though they are sent to the same domain? (http://localhost:9000/)

Thanks ahead.

EDIT: The Set-Cookie Header:

```
session=sHwQFdcQLYN2Pdrh; Max-Age=3600; Expires=Tue, 05 May 2020 16:24:13 GMT; Path=/; HTTPOnly
```

Comment: What, exactly, does the `Set-Cookie` header look like? What URL are you testing where the cookie *doesn't* get subsequently set?

Comment: Does `http://localhost:9000/login` handle the request directly or does it redirect somewhere (e.g. `http://localhost:9000/login/`) before the `Set-Cookie` header is sent back?

Comment: Check the cookie in the browser's dev tools, specifically its `path`. If the path isn't `/`, but for instance `/login`, then the cookie is only sent for `/login/...` requests.

Comment: @Quentin I'll add the set-cookie header to the answer shortly, cause it's probably relevant. I try the URL http://localhost:9000/schools next, and a cookie is not sent to the server. the /login path handles the request directly

Comment: @ChrisG path is indeed /. I just added the Set-Cookie header to the question.

Comment: @ChrisG also, the cookie never appears in the memory section of the dev tools. Only as a part of the response. I thought it isn't sent at all but then it was sent with the same request again...